# Linked list insertion/deletion efficiency

Tags: arrays, data-structures, linked-list

Traditionally, linked lists are recommended over arrays when we want to perform insertions/deletions at random locations.This is because while using linked list(singly linked list), we just have to change the `next` and `previous` pointers of the adjacent nodes. Whereas in arrays, we have to shove numerous elements to make space for the new element(in case of insertion).

However, the process of finding the location of insertion/deletion in case of linked list is very costly(sequential search) as compared to arrays(random access), specially when we have large data.

Does this factor significantly decrease the efficiency of insertion/deletion in a linked lists over arrays? Or is the time required to shove the elements in case of an array a bigger problem than sequential access?

Comment: Some nice graphs here comparing the performance (bottom line is inefficiency of vector shows with increased size of elements stored) https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/12/cpp-benchmark-vector-list-deque.html

Answer (score 1):

> However, the process of finding the location of insertion/deletion in
>   case of linked list is very costly(sequential search) as compared to
>   arrays(random access), specially when we have large data.

Random access doesn't help anything if you are searching for an element and don't know where it is, and if you do know where it is and have like a pointer or index to it, there's no longer a search involved to access the element whether you're using linked lists or arrays. Only case where random-access helps in this case is if the array is sorted, in which case the random-access enables a binary search.

> Does this factor significantly decrease the efficiency of
>   insertion/deletion in a linked lists over arrays? Or is the time
>   required to shove the elements in case of an array a bigger problem
>   than sequential access?

Generally not at least with unordered sequences since, again, both arrays and linked lists require a linear-time search to find an element. And if people had a need for searching frequently in their critical paths for non-trivial input sizes, often people use hash tables or balanced binary trees or tries or something of that sort instead.

Often arrays are preferred over linked lists in a lot of performance-critical fields for reasons that don't relate to algorithmic complexity. It's because arrays are guaranteed to contiguously store their elements. That provides very good locality of reference for sequential processing.

There are also ways to remove from arrays in constant-time. As one example, if you want to remove the nth element from an array in constant-time, just swap it with the last element in the array and remove the last one in constant-time. You don't necessarily have to shuffle all the elements over to close a gap if you're allowed to reorder the elements.

Linked lists may or may not store their nodes contiguously. They often become a lot more useful in performance-critical contexts if they do, like if they store their nodes in an array (either through an array-based container or allocator). Otherwise traversing them can lead to cache misses galore with potentially a cache miss for every single node being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

> the process of finding the location of insertion/deletion in case of linked list is very costly(sequential search) as compared to arrays *(random access)*

The comparison is wrong, since you are comparing the efficiency of insertion/deletion operations. Instead compare these two factors:

1. Sequential search in a linked-list having time complexity `O(n)`
2. Copy array elements in order to shove. May require to copy upto `n` number of array elements.

In array : If the underlying type is POD it can just `realloc`, but if not it must move them with the object's `operator=`.

So you can see that not everything is in favor of *array* usage. *Linked List* obviates the need to copy the same data again and again.

> , specially when we have large data.

That would mean more number of array elements to be copied while shoving.